# How do I call a function whose name is only known in a variable in python?

Tags: python, function, import

How do I call a function whose name is only known in one variable?

I have an interface scanning for a dynamic anmount of modules in a directory and this modules contains functions that i need to call. But the names of the functions are given by a variable like this:

```
def do_function(function_name: str):
    if function_name in dynamic_module_anmount.functions:
        return function_name
```

While function_name is given as a string and i want to call the function with this name for return.

Comment: "I have an interface scanning for a dynamic anmount of modules in a directory" why? Why don't you have a defined API?

Comment: This question needs more detail. Show us the string value of `function_name` and explain where the function that it names is defined.

Comment: You could use `eval(function_name)`, but be aware of the security risk.

Comment: Well, there wouldn't be a need for `eval` if you create a dict of executables. But I don't understand this question at all. The whole premise seems like poor design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, if you have the function name as a string f,and want to call it without arguments.

```
function_name = 'dir'
f = eval(function_name)
print(f())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the getattr() function of the python, to call your function dynamically.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-getattr-method/

here is a simple explanation for that,
for calling function , I think you can use like getattr(obj, 'func')()